# How to redirect to previous view with kwargs after form submit in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, view

I have standard Django class-based FormView with an overridden get_success_url method called upon a successful call to form_valid.

Here's the get_success_url method currently:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    """Redirect to same view for message flashing"""
    return reverse(
        'manage_property',
        kwargs={'slug': self.kwargs['property_slug']}
    )
```

Users will arrive at my form from at least three different views. I'd like to redirect them back to the view they started from with the appropriate kwargs passed.

For example, one user might start from here:

```
url(r'^properties/(?P<property_slug>[-\w]+)/leads/(?P<offer_pk>[\d]+)/$',
    "manage_property_lead", name="manage_property_lead"),
```

To arrive here:

```
url(
    r'^properties/(?P<property_slug>[-\w]+)/send-email/$',
    SendEmail.as_view(),
    name='send_email'
),
```

But they might also start from here:

```
url(r'^properties/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/offers/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$',
    'manage_property_offer', name='manage_property_offer'),
```

What's the best practice in Django to ensure I have what I need to send them back to the appropriate view after a successful form submit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view which handles the form, you can get the value of the referring view/page (if any) from `request.META['HTTP_REFERER]'`.

```
def form_view(request):
    redirect_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', None) or '/'
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Comment: What about any kwargs that are needed? How do I pass those to the view I'm redirecting back to?

Comment: You can pass those as `GET` parameters, like - `?key=val&key2=val2` if confidentiality is not a problem.  Otherwise, you can save those *kwargs* in current session and access them in another view.

Comment: @PatrickBeeson Are you talking about `property_slug`? Well, it will be there in `HTTP_REFERER` URL already. So I don't think there's any need to supply that parameter manually.